# Track score from SCORM 2004

Tags: scorm2004

I am creating a LMS portal and planning to use adobe presenter as the online training quiz builder. After publishing the quiz (scorm 2004), I am not sure how to track the user's score. I already google it but could not find any working example. After searching google, I came to this point that I need javascript to track the score. But no luck yet.

If anyone knows, could you please help me in regards to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Implementing a SCORM conformant LMS is a non-trivial task. Get started by reading up on it [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/) and then dive into the technical parts. You will then want to download the official [spec documents](http://www.adlnet.gov/capabilities/scorm/scorm-2004-4th) from ADL and read those.